# How to create GStreamer RTSP server with variable frame rate

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp, python-gstreamer

I have an application which requires me to consume an RTSP stream, extract frames from the video, perform some processing on the video frames, annotate the frames, then restream the video as a new RTSP stream. Sounds simple enough.

I am using the following code which I obtained from another SO answer:

```
import gi
import cv2
import os

# import required library like Gstreamer and GstreamerRtspServer
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GObject


# Sensor Factory class which inherits the GstRtspServer base class and add
# properties to it.
class SensorFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self, **properties):
        super(SensorFactory, self).__init__(**properties)
        
        # Create a connection to our input RTSP stream and obtain the width and height
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtspsrc location=rtsp://root:admin@192.168.88.248/stream1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=3 drop=true")
        width  = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) 
        print(width)
        print(height)

        self.number_frames = 0
        self.fps = 30
        self.duration = 1 / self.fps * Gst.SECOND  # duration of a frame in nanoseconds
        self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                             'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width={},height={},framerate={}/1 ' \
                             '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ' \
                             '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                             '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96' \
                             .format(width, height, self.fps)

    

    # Method for grabbing frames from the video capture, process, then pushing annotated images to streaming buffer
    def on_need_data(self, src, lenght):
        if self.cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if ret:
               
                # --------------------------
                # --------------------------
                # Do processing here       
                # --------------------------
                # --------------------------

                data = frame.tobytes()
                buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
                buf.fill(0, data)
                buf.duration = self.duration
                timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
                buf.pts = buf.dts = int(timestamp)
                buf.offset = timestamp
                self.number_frames += 1
                retval = src.emit('push-buffer', buf)
                print('pushed buffer, frame {}, duration {} ns, durations {} s'.format(self.number_frames,
                                                                                       self.duration,
                                                                                       self.duration / Gst.SECOND))
                if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
                    print(retval)
    # attach the launch string to the override method
    def do_create_element(self, url):
        return Gst.parse_launch(self.launch_string)
    
    # attaching the source element to the rtsp media
    def do_configure(self, rtsp_media):
        self.number_frames = 0
        appsrc = rtsp_media.get_element().get_child_by_name('source')
        appsrc.connect('need-data', self.on_need_data)

# Rtsp server implementation where we attach the factory sensor with the stream uri
class GstServer(GstRtspServer.RTSPServer):
    def __init__(self, **properties):
        super(GstServer, self).__init__(**properties)
        self.factory = SensorFactory()
        self.factory.set_shared(True)
        self.get_mount_points().add_factory("/my_stream", self.factory)
        self.attach(None)

# initializing the threads and running the stream on loop.
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
server = GstServer()
loop = GObject.MainLoop()
loop.run()


# To connect:
# rtsp://localhost:8554/my_stream
```

I perform my processing in the section labeled:

```
                # --------------------------
                # --------------------------
                # Do processing here       
                # --------------------------
                # --------------------------
```

Now this code works great for when the processing is constant time, because then I know the output rtsp stream fps.
However, my processing has a non constant time; the time taken depends on the input frame from the source rtsp stream. For context, I am building a face recognition application and the processing time is ~50ms + 100ms for every detected face in the frame.

How can I make the output rtsp stream work with this variable frame rate?

My guess is that I need to modify the gstreamer pipeline string:

```
        self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                             'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width={},height={},framerate={}/1 ' \
                             '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ' \
                             '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                             '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96' \
                             .format(width, height, self.fps)
```

And I probably need to change this part as well:

```
                buf.duration = self.duration
                timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
                buf.pts = buf.dts = int(timestamp)
                buf.offset = timestamp
```

Comment: Did you find an resolution?